# Extract Azure Ad B2C Public Key from Modulus and Exponent only?

Tags: c#, jwt, token, azure-ad-b2c, verification

I want to verify the signature of the id_token, that I receive from Azure Ad B2C.

When I go to the metadata endpoint to find the keys, I'm only given *n* and *e*.

*kid* is as far as I understand the "key-id" which is matching the one contained in my id_token

```
{
"keys": [
    {
        "kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk",
        "nbf": 1493763266,
        "use": "sig",
        "kty": "RSA",
        "e": "AQAB",
        "n": "tVKUtcx_n9rt5afY_2WFNvU6PlFMggCatsZ3l4RjKxH0jgdLq6CScb0P3ZGXYbPzXvmmLiWZizpb-h0qup5jznOvOr-Dhw9908584BSgC83YacjWNqEK3urxhyE2jWjwRm2N95WGgb5mzE5XmZIvkvyXnn7X8dvgFPF5QwIngGsDG8LyHuJWlaDhr_EPLMW4wHvH0zZCuRMARIJmmqiMy3VD4ftq4nS5s8vJL0pVSrkuNojtokp84AtkADCDU_BUhrc2sIgfnvZ03koCQRoZmWiHu86SuJZYkDFstVTVSR0hiXudFlfQ2rOhPlpObmku68lXw-7V-P7jwrQRFfQVXw"
    }
]
}
```

Microsoft says that you can generate the public key from these two parameters, but I have absolutely no clue about how to do so. And every time I find a guide online it is not in C# (my coding language).

Source:
[Web sign-in with OpenID Connect in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect)

I've found libraries to verify the signature, but I also want to see the public key itself, if thats possible, and test it on JWT.IO:

[image: Desired state]

I really hope someone can help me out on this.

Comment: I just modified the linked answer to cover your question about verification on jwt.io

Comment: You can follow https://play.golang.org/p/7wWMBOp10R and replace the variable 'js' with the value you obtain from your discovery url. Run the snippet and copy the entire output to https://jwt.io along with your jwt token to be verified and see if the signature is valid.